# Error : Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mysql, web-services

I am getting following error when I try to open MySQL Connection;

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

**EDIT : **
ConnectionString :

```
public string strProvider = "Server=00.00.00.00;Database=someDatabase;Uid=someUser;Pwd=somePassword";
```

Code I am using :

```
string getCompany = "Select * From tbl_company";
MySqlConnection objMyCon = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
objMyCon.Open();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(getCompany, objMyCon);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
objMyCon.Close();
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Paste some code for yourself !

Comment: Are you able to connect to mysql from the command line using the client with the connection parameters you are specifying in your code?

Comment: Are you able to connect via MySQL Query browser? what is your connection string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868784/mysql-exception-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I boldly would suggest that no of the sql servers you try to conenct to exists. Check the connection string (App-Settings) or the servers.

hth

Mario

Comment: Thanks! It was problem with database creation method. I missed out on one of the settings while creating the database.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949234/mysql-visual-studio-2008-godaddy-fail

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in my earlier post: the connection string is the issue:

00.00.00.00

is just an invalid IP Adress, sorry. Either use localhost or your computer's name (if the mysql server is on your pc)

hth

Mario

Comment: Here 00.00.00.00 is for exmaple purpose only. Actually it is my server IP

Comment: I am using MySQL server. I can use it through IE. But I cant use it in Toad. Is there anything I can do  on server side?

Comment: is the tcp listen port (default: 3306) up and accepting connections?