# mySQL Exception: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. through C#

Tags: c#, mysql

strProvider = "Data Source=184.67.33.33;Database=abcd;User ID=abcd;Password=12345678"
is not working   and

strProvider = "Data Source=184.67.33.33;Initial Catalog=abcd;User ID=abcd;Password=12345678"
is also not working.

it gives error at `objmycon.Open()`

I am using above string as my connection String and it gives mySQL Exception

I am not able to find any thing wrong with this.But still gives error

what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using 'Initial Catalog' instead of 'Database'?

Comment: no.not yet.how i could use initial catalog?i mean what detail i need to put as its value?

Comment: you would put in strProvider = "Data Source=184.67.33.33;Initial Catalog=abcd;User ID=abcd;Password=12345678"

Comment: after changing it to `Initial Catalog` it still shows error `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.` at `objmycon.Open()`

Comment: Is it on the default port ? else you will have to specify the port also like `DataSource=184.67.33.33:3360`

Comment: Try this string - 'User Id=abcd;Host=184.67.33.33;Port=3306;Database=abcd;Password=your_password'. Specify your port and password.

Comment: yes this way it is working now.thanks

Answer (score 1):

There could be some reasons for that issue.

1. Check your **hosts** file. (Go to Run menu and past+<kbd>enter</kbd> `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`. Open Notepad.exe in Administrator mode and edit **hosts** file.)

It should have

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost   ::1             localhost
```

1. Very probably that you are using some Port to connect to MySQL. So you have to include Port number into connection string.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

So it should like

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```

Usually Port is **3306** so be careful what you are input like a MySQL Port number.