# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, database

hy!

I just created a little MYSQL remote c# tool.

The Problem is, that i get the error :Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

CODE:

```
string myConnectionString = "SERVER=http://xxx;PORT=3306;" +
                            "DATABASE=xxx;" +
                            "UID=root;" +
                            "PASSWORD=xxx;";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
            MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM USER";
            MySqlDataReader Reader;
            connection.Open();//Here ocurres the error
            Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            string tmp ="";
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                string row = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
                tmp += row + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(tmp);

            connection.Close();
```

When i use MYSQL Workbench from remote i can normaly login

Please help

Comment: `SERVER=http://xxx` , is the http necessary?

Comment: you was right, now it worked, post it as answer and i will tick it

Comment: More than necessary is it even valid, i suspect that should just be a domnain name or ip the "http://" is what is causing the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868784/mysql-exception-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SERVER=http://xxx` the pre-pend of `http://` is not required for database connection in this case.