# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts when checking connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to Mysql database through vb.net
However I run into the error:

```
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts
```

[image]
Here is the code:

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class DBProject_1
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=root;database=My_Mysql_Database"
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful")
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

I have even tried to use

```
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=**127.0.0.1**;userid=root;password=root;database=My_Mysql_Database"
```

This may be the reason:
When I test connection of the Mysql database in Mysql Workbench the test fails.
The error is `Failed to Connect to Mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root`
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868784/mysql-exception-unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-through

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this `ConnectionString`:

```
 MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=My_Mysql_Database;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but no it doesn't change the problem

Comment: Based on your comment and your last edit it is obvious that you are using invalid credentials or root account is missing. Check this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641984/mysql-cant-access-root-account)

Comment: Had to reinstall mysql server after my pc was damaged. Now it has connected.Thanks to both

Answer (score 2):

The "Can't connect to MySQL server" error usually is the result of not being able to reach the server, e.g. if it is not running or it is on a remote machine but firewalls block access. See also the [video I added to the MySQL channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY) for how to set up connections.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that MySql Service is running by typing "services.msc" in the "run".
I hope it will help you!

Comment: In case the service is not there, what then?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
But I was a server, in a domain, and now the server is outside the domain.

I try to change the rulesin firewall of the server (where there is MySql server).
So go to inbound rules, and search the 2 Mysql rules.

Open them and search th Advanced item.
Then check Domain, or/and Private, or/and Public

(for me, Domain was the only cheked option, not good for me because I 'm now outside the domain).

Hope it helps ! 
Cheers :)