# How to create connection with online mysql database in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am creating connection with my online mysql database but it gives me the error (unable to connect to any of the specified Mysql hosts).

this is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection("Server=http://eu5org.freewebhostingarea.com; Port=3306; Database=477928; Uid=477928; Pwd=password123;");
        con1.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Established");                
        con1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

how could i correct this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts when checking connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962923/unable-to-connect-to-any-of-the-specified-mysql-hosts-when-checking-connection)

Comment: i have established the connection locally. but when connecting to online database it gives me the error.

Comment: remove `http://` from the connection string

Comment: Are you sure you have the right address for the server? It is usually different from the admin login panel

Comment: Just looked at the FAQ for the address in your connection string and saw this.. Q: What is database host?  A: Only  localhost. External access is not allowed.

Comment: when i open my online database the above address comes in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the hosting you have only allows a server address of `localhost` any other address will fail.

Comment: so i can not access it?

Comment: No, not unless the application or website is on the same server as the database. The only address the hosting company allows for the database connection is `localhost` ie same machine.

Comment: You may be able to change this by logging in to your hosting control panel.

Comment: @user910683 As I have told the OP the hosting company states in their FAQ only localhost connections are allowed.